# Why does it not find object "x"

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to load a shiny app to predict the next most probable word after a user input. It works fine locally, but when I publish it at shiny I get an error and the following message in the logs:
Error in PredictWord3: cannot find object "x".

I have tried defining x with a starting value, did not work

My UI

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Predicting next word"),

  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       textInput("Word",
                 "Enter your word or phrase"
                  )
    ),

    # Show the word
    mainPanel(
       textOutput("Word1")
    )
  )
))
```

My server

```
library(shiny)
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
library(reticulate)
use_python("python3.5", require = FALSE)
x<-a
source("PredictWord3.R")
readRDS(("freq1.rds"))
readRDS(("freq2.rds"))
readRDS(("freq3.rds"))
readRDS(("freq4.rds"))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  z<-reactive({PredictWord3(input$Word)})
  output$Word1<-renderText({z()

  })

})
```

My PredictWord3 funcion

```
PredictWord3<-function(sentence){

  #cleaning the sentence as the training data
  sentence<-tokens(sentence, "word", remove_numbers=TRUE, 
            remove_punct=TRUE, remove_symbols=TRUE, remove_separators=TRUE, 
            remove_twitter=TRUE, remove_hyphens=TRUE, remove_url = TRUE, ngrams=1, 
            concatenator=" ")
  #Counting the words
    words<-unlist(sentence, " ")
    wordcount<-length(words)

  #Finding the most probable next word if there are three or more words
  if (wordcount>2){
    words<-tail(words, n=3)
    a<-filter(freq4, freq4[,1]==words[1] & freq4[,2]==words[2] & freq4[,3]==words[3])
    x<-a[1,4]
  }  
  #Finding the most probable next word if there are two words
  if (wordcount==2 | is.na(x)){
    words<-tail(words, n=2)
    a<-filter(freq3, freq3[,1]==words[1] & freq3[,2]==words[2])
    x<-a[1,3]
  }
  #Finding the most probable next word if there is only one word
  if ((sentence!=""&wordcount==1) | is.na(x)){
    words<-tail(words, n=1)
    a<-filter(freq2, freq2[,1]==words[1])
    x<-a[1,2]
  }
  #Finding the most probable next word if there is no word
  if (sentence==""){ 
    x<-names(freq1[1])
  }

  x
}
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: I guess because `x` is not a global variable and not passed to the function as a variable.

Comment: I hope you do not mind another question, how should I do it so it works?

Comment: The best option would be passing x as a variable to the function: `PredictWord3<-function(sentence, x){...}` and than calling the function in the server as `PredictWord3(sentence, x)`. You could also make x a global variable with `x <<- a`.